Looking for a method to replace a PNG's transparent background with any other color in Linux without using ImageMagick
When given a png with a transparent background, even without any of it being visible it causes problems with the rest of my code, so I'm looking for a way to remove the transparent background either using an open source solution or the default libpng library - preferably in linux.
I have tried using ImageMagick and it's how I've verified that converting the transparent background to that of any color solves my issues. I'm just looking for a different solution than ImageMagick.

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the information guides in the help center (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example - And Show Code As Text, Not An Image" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Post your code and an example image. What programming language or tool do you want to use to do the same?  Can you use Python/OpenCV?

You can do that in many ways. Here's an example using the NetPBM suite and using this red image with a transparent circular hole in the centre:


The steps are as follows:

make a blue background image over which to composite
convert your PNG to PAM
composite your image over the background
convert resulting PPM back to PNG


ppmmake blue 200 100 > background.ppm
pngtopam -alphapam YOURIMAGE.png > foreground.pam
pamcomp foreground.pam background.ppm > result.ppm
pamtopng result.ppm > result.png

TL;DR
That's all a bit of a palaver, so leverage the power of Unix to chain lots of things done well together and you get:
pamcomp <(pngtopam -alphapam YOURIMAGE.png) <(ppmmake blue 200 100) | pamtopng - > result.png



Depending on how your PNG is actually constructed, and at the loss of flexibility in the colour replacing the transparency, you may find this command, which just ditches the alpa channel, is enough:
pngtopam YOURIMAGE.png | pamtopng - > result.png


Other ways of approaching this might be:

PIL/Pillow and 3-4 lines of Python
OpenCV and 3-4 lines of Python
gd and 4-5 lines of PHP
CImg and 10-11 lines of C++


With PIL/Pillow, that might look like this:
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open('YOURIMAGE.png')          # open image
bg = Image.new('RGB',im.size, 'yellow')   # make yellow background, same size
bg.paste(im, mask=im)                     # composite your image over background
bg.save('result.png')                     # save result

